# Descomponer un String en partes

Tags: vb.net, string

talvez usar el metodo **.split**? , bueno quiero separar todo este texto en partes con **vb.net** .

**texto>**

```
{"error":false,"title":"Alan Walker - Diamond Heart (feat. Sophia Somajo)","duration":218,"file":"http:\/\/michaelbelgium.me\/ytconverter\/download\/sJXZ9Dok7u8.mp3"}
```

Quiero separarlo en partes , como cuando se lee un archivo **.ini** , **asi >**

el **"error":** | **"title":** | **"duration"** | **"file":** | quiero obtener el resultado que le sigue. Por ejemplo el de **error** el resultado es **false** , es algo así como leer un **.ini**.

gracias de antemano!!

Comment: ok puedes meter todo en un array y asi es mas facil de manejar el json o si lo que quieres es leer mas facil el json te aconsejo convertirlo a xml. Espero te sirva, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta a mi pregunta es deserializar un JSON , para ello esta esta librería > 
[Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Gracias a **@Pablo Puente** por la respuesta.

Comment: si la respuesta de Pablo fue la que te resolvió el problema, la que debe ir con la palomita verde es la de el y no la tuya

Comment: Te sugiero editar esta publicación, revisa [ask]